# ユーザ同士を関連づけるDB設計

Tags: swift, mysql, sql, database

二人のシフトを管理できるiOSアプリを作成しようと考えています。
システム構成的には、クライアントサイドはswift3で実装して、サーバサイドはgoからDBを操作しようと考えていました。

そこで、DB設計をしていたのですが、二人のリレーションをどうやって定義すれば良いかという問題に当たりました。
僕が考えた候補は二つあり

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  `uuid` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `pairs` (
  `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user1_id` INTEGER,
  `user2_id` INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user1_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user2_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`)
);
```

のようにユーザ間のリレーションを定義するテーブルを作成するか、

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  `uuid` VARCHAR(255),
  `partner_id` INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`)
);
```

のように一つのテーブルで自身のテーブルを参照する、という感じです。
どちらの方が扱い安く、スマートでしょうか？
また、もっといい設計があれば教えていただきたいです。
また、iOSでデータベースを扱うのにはRealmが一般的だと思いますが、
複数のiOSの端末間で扱う場合はサーバを立ててDBを扱うやり方で大丈夫でしょうか？
ご回答お待ちしております。

Comment: 「扱い安く、スマート」かどうかではなく、あなたのアプリが実現しようとする事柄の要件に関わってくる問題です。前者ではどのユーザーも複数のユーザーと結びつけられる(いわゆる多対多)のに対して、後者の設計ではどのユーザもある一つのユーザにしか結びつけられません(複数のユーザーが同じユーザに結びつく可能性もあるので、多対１と言われます)。あなたが実現したいのはどちらでしょうか？また最後の部分(「iOSでデータベースを扱うのにはRealmが一般的」かどうかは大いに疑問なので、置いておいて)「複数のiOSの端末間で扱う場合はサーバを立ててDBを扱う」については、複数のiOSデバイス間でデータを共用する方法はサーバを立てる以外にはないと思っていいでしょう。(iOS開発として問題になるのは、そのインターフェース…REST+JSONにするか、など…です。)

Comment: 素早いご回答ありがとうございます。

提示した二つの例に「多対多」と「１対多」の違いがあることには気づきませんでした。
私がやりたかったことでは、一人のユーザは自分以外のユーザ一人としか結びついて欲しくなかったので「１対１」であると思います。
Realmが一般的というのは主観でしかなかったので、自分の知識不足でした。
複数のiOS端末間でデータのやり取りをするのは主にサーバを立てる方法を利用するのですね。
私はできれば１対１のリレーションを作成したかったので、お返事いただいた内容を元にもう少し考えてみたいと思います。

Comment: 追加情報や質問の訂正はコメントではなく質問の編集によって行ってください